# C++ insertion sorting elements

Tags: c++, sorting, insertion-sort

Other way for elements to be in function instead of main program?

```
void insertionSort(int array[], int number)
{

    int j, temp;
    for (int i = 1; i<number; i++)
    {
        j = i;
        while (j>0 && array[j - 1]>array[j])
        {
            temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j - 1];
            array[j - 1] = temp;

            j--;
        }
    }

}



int main()
{

    int number = 8;

    int array[] = { 2, 7, 5, 6, 4, 8, 1, 3 };

    insertionSort(array, 8);

    for (int i = 0; i<number; i++)
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain `Other way for elements to be in function instead of main program?`.  Do you want the array to be in the sort function instead of main?

Comment: Yes,if that's possible

Comment: ... You could just remove the "array" and "number" parameters from the insertionSort procedure, and introduce them as local variables inside the procedure itself the same way you did in main.

I don't know what's the point of such a procedure though

Answer (score 1):

While the data to be sorted *could* be moved into the sort function, doing so creates a function that's pretty much useless--since it only ever sorts one set of data, it's equivalent to `return {1, 2, 3, 4 5, 6, 7, 8};`

Your insertion sort is also a bit of a mess. Pseudo-code for an insertion sort normally looks something like this:

```
for i in 1 to size do 
    temp = array[i]
    for j in i downto 0 and array[j-1] > temp do
        array[j] = array[j-1]
    array[j] = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do not do this.  A function is supposed to be a reusable piece of code.  If you hardcode the array into the function then that function could only ever sort the array that is in the function and you would have to edit the array in the function to sort something different.  By passing the array to the function now you have the ability to pass any array to the function and it will get sorted.  You could even call the function multiple times with different arrays in the same program and they will be sorted.

I will also mention that if you move the array to be in the sort function then it won't be in `main()` and you won't be able to print out the array in `main()` as you have it now.

Comment: Okay,thank you ever much.I'm beginner i make lots of mistakes and i have many things to figure it out.